# unable to complete django installation

Tags: django, python-3.x, installation

I downloaded the necessary files from the link https://github.com/django/django.git  and pasted them in to my virtual env directory

After setting up and activating the virtualenv, when I run the following command:

```
$ pip install -e django/
```

It produces this error:

> (ENV) C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install -e django/ django/ should either
>   be a path to a local project or a VCS url beginning with svn+, git+,
>   hg+, or bzr+

I am a Windows user. I think the command is for bash not for cmd.

**Is it necessary to use this git tool to finally work with django ?**

> As instructed on the Django website :
>
> [image: As instructed on the Django website]

Comment: Why are you installing the development version at all? You're clearly new to Django and development, so you should follow [the instructions to install a released version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/install/#install-the-django-code).

Comment: (That error is because you didn't follow the instructions properly; you shouldn't be in the WINDOWS\system32 directory, for a start. You don't need git to install Django, but you *do* need git or a similar tool to do any actual development. But, again, these are not the instructions you should be reading at this point.)

Answer (score 2):

If you're just starting out with Django development I'd recommend looking at some YouTube videos before jumping into the Django docs. Personally when I was starting out I found that the docs were quite hard to understand in the beginning, but as you get better you can refer back to them more and more.

Here's a [good beginner video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgGIqRFvFFk&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBlmzzFcLgDhKTTfNLfX1IK) to get you started.

In any case, I would recommend using `virtualenvwrapper-win` so that you can work on multiple Django projects without any conflicts.

First, ensure that you have [added Python to the Windows environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7). Open CMD and run `pip install virtualenvwrapper-win`.

Then `cd` to whichever directory your project files will be in and run `mkvirtualenv projectname`.

Finally run `setprojectdir path/to/folder`

Now whenever you want to enter that virtual environment and work on your project all you have to do is run the command `workon projectname` and it'll do the rest for you. You'll know it worked if on each new line in the command prompt it gives you *(projectname)* in brackets.

To actually install Django all you need to run is `pip install django` while in the virtual environment.

Comment: I was happy to see a civilized answer as opposed to the above comments which are rather terse and presumptuous on the OP's intent.  Personally, I ran into this exact problem, but for me it was a case of not paying attention to where I was in the documentation.

Comment: thanks @lee, I find SO can be quite a hostile environment sometimes, especially when you're just starting out and don't know how to correctly format questions & research other Q&A before posting. Glad to hear you got it all working!

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I suppose that you are trying to install django inside your virtual directory. If that is correct you dont need to get it from git.
Alternate way is to create a directory "main" and then project directory "mydjangoproject" inside it and a virtual environment "env".

```
C:\>mkdir main
C:\>cd main
C:\main>mkdir mydjangoproject
C:\main>virtualenv env
```

Now activate the virtual environment.

```
C:\main>env\Scripts\activate
```

Then install all the package in it. e.g

```
(env) C:\main>pip install django
```